# 'DataGridView' VS 'DataGrid' when Convert to 'DataSet'?

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview, c#-3.0

I bound excel data with DataGridView controller successfully. 
Then I try to save the DataGridView contents to xml file.
I want to implement as belwo, but throw exception. 
How can I fix it using DataGridView? (VS2008 used)

```
// I tried to implement using this style.But throw exception.
DataSet ds = (DataSet)(dataGridView1.DataSource);  

// One online tutorial posted as this style below
DataSet ds = (DataSet)(dataGrid1.DataSource);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a breakpoint in the debugger, check what class type `dataGridView1.DataSource` actually is.

For instance, you might find that if you are using a `BindingSource` class between the grid view and the data set, that the views data source is not a `DataSet`, but instead a `System.Data.DataView` which wraps the `DataSet`. 
You would then have to use:

```
DataSet ds = ((DataView)dataGridView1.DataSource).Table.DataSet;
```